# Enable / disable Elements When div element gets focus

Tags: jquery, onfocus

I've certain number of Input elements inside a div. When any of the input element inside the div gets focus I want disable an element outside the div? How can do this in jquery??

Comment: show some code ,what have you tried?

Comment: Show the initial work and effort you did.

Comment: please provide what is inside Div and what is outside Div....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following HTML as an example:

```
<div class="div">
     <input type="text" />
     <input type="text" /> 
     <input type="text" /> 
</div>

<input type="text" class="b"/>
```

One can use the following script, using the [**focus**](http://api.jquery.com/focus) and [**blur**](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) events:

```
$('.div input[type="text"]').on('focus', function(){
    $('.b').prop('disabled', true);

}).on('blur', function(){
     $('.b').prop('disabled', false); 
});
```

#### [Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wZ4P/)

Comment: +1, wihtout OP giving any information or markup this is a valid example. Although, the use of classes on any controls which should disable/enable other elements may or may not be slightly more efficient than targeting all inputs by either specific type or just `input`.